# How to save ansible debug logs to a single file

Tags: ansible

Goal to achieve - check the status of "filebeat" & "Telegraf" service from ansible on 20 production servers. In case any service is stopped on any servers, I could get alert.

```
---
- hosts: ALL
  tasks:
   - name: checking service status
     command: systemctl status "{{ item }}"
     with_items:
          - filebeat
          - telegraf
     register: result
     ignore_errors: yes
   - debug:
       var: result
```

Got Below output -

```
ok: [10.5.10.10] => {
    "result.results[0].stdout": "* filebeat.service - Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.\n   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)\n   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-08-06 11:07:34 IST; 3 weeks 6 days ago\n     Docs: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat\n Main PID: 102961 (filebeat)\n   CGroup: /system.slice/filebeat.service\n           `-102961 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat\n\nWarning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable."
}
ok: [10.5.10.11] => {
    "result.results[0].stdout": "* filebeat.service - Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.\n   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)\n   Active: inactive (dead)\n     Docs: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat"
}
```

How could I store these outputs in a file on my ansible server. So that I could apply alert in case any service is not running on any server.

Comment: If you want to send an alert via ansible then you can check out the [ansible notification modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/list_of_notification_modules.html).

Otherwise, you can redirect the output of your ansible command to a file and then generate alert using your custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why don't you parse the output and see a red sign when one of them is not active?
2. Answering your question:
   What I would do is saving the output to a file and copying that file back to your ansible server then appending all the results.